# I want to compare the split value of column using neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am new in Neo4j. I have split(break) data of FT by this way.I don't get idea to compare the split value of FT in order to declare winner team.

Round,Date,Team 1,FT,HT,Team 2

1,(Fri) 11 Aug 2017 (32),Arsenal FC,4-3,2-2,Leicester City FC

1,(Sat) 12 Aug 2017 (32),Crystal Palace FC,0-3,0-2,Huddersfield Town AFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FTScore as an array, you do not need to Unwind.

Something like this:

```
LOAD CSV FROM"file:///ft.csv" AS row 
WITH row, split(row[3], "-") AS ScoreFT
RETURN 
CASE 
  WHEN ScoreFT[0] > ScoreFT[1] THEN 'Home win' 
  WHEN ScoreFT[0] < ScoreFT[1] THEN 'Away win' 
ELSE 'Draw'
END
```

But you have other options:

- Just to store the goals, and evaluate at query time
- Load the CSV first and run another update query to determine the winner team

I hope it helps.

Comment: You can use the same approach. Maybe you should consider to improve your data model a bit, you can get inspiration from this blog post how to store games.

But you can split the date too, using space separator, if you store it in this format. But I would recommend to use a better date format, if you want to query based on specific dates.
WITH split(row[1], " ") AS Date
where Date[2]="Aug"
return row

Comment: I recommend to load into the database first, and then you can do aggregation queries in cypher. You can use count, sum, etc. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/aggregating/

Comment: Thank you so much sir!Grateful for your help!